# If G is a bipartite graph with 6 vertices and 9 edges then the chromatic number of G bar?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Here for bipartite graph chromatic number will be the 2 but if we have 6 vertices and 9 edges then it will become complete bipartite graph so its complement graph will be the null graph. So, its chromatic number will be 1, Right? I'm little bit confused here because i got this question and answer mentioned 3. So, what is the right answer?

Comment: A complete graph on 6 vertices has $\binom62=15$ vertices, so your graph will have $15-9=6$ vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a complete bipartite graph, but its complement is not empty! Note that in the complement you will have edges between the 3 vertices on each side, so $\bar{G}$ is the union of two $K_3$s. Each $K_n$ has chromatic number $n$, so the answer is 3.

Comment: Yes undersood! means its both side contains K3 so, chromatic number for K3 is 3 So, answer will be 3.